# library returns multi-byte strings

Tags: c++, string, static-libraries, utf

I'm writing a program using code::blocks on a win10 pc. The executable part uses a static library that is developed in the same workspace and they are compiled together. c::b are setup with the default encoding (windows-1252) when opening files. I understand that it's an old sort of one-byte encoding ..
I have fiddled with shifting the encoding, but that quickly changes the appearence of litterals after reopening the workspace .. and it's a quick way to shut-down on doing things wrong. c::b are setup with a default 'C' locale.

Anyway ..
I have a vector of const strings returned from the library .. and I recieve it in strings that changed size after the char-contents appears to have been transformed by a few multi-byte letters. Sure, the problem is the danish letters used. The odd ones turns into 2 byte.
If I display the 256 chars of the console I see the char-symbols of the odd danish letters there. Why doesn't it find...
That must have to do with the c::b locale being 'C'. So, I start looking for the pc-system locale-name, the danish one. Trying to use

```
int GetUserDefaultLocaleName(
  LPWSTR lpLocaleName,
  int    cchLocaleName
);
```

is not for the faint of heart, but I got a gist of it somewhere else in this forum. None the less, a consol-program testing it does not recognize anything.
Trying that program on setting a new locale ( `locale("en-GB") or locale("en-US")` ) is a quick way to exit the program. The idea was to `cout.imbue(..)` to see if that would bring.

Anyway, I'm not going to use the library strings directly, but each letter should be an identifier into a map of textures covering an image of an appropriate letter. If it wasn't for the presence of a single 3-byte character I might have a chance using wchar. I could leave out a representation for that particular symbol, but now it's becomming a matter of principles. It's not the first time that I'm around locale and getting absolutely nothing out of it.
Bjarne Stroustrup adds this example in his book:

```
u8"The official vowels in Danish are: a, e, i, o, u, \u00E6, \u00F8, \u00E5 and y"
```

and wisely adds "Printing that string appropriately gives you:". Well, I've never seen those vowels appear properly. I have 25 years of hobby-programming experience and solved problems to my satisfaction. But, this seems to reveal how stoopid I really am.

..................... edits.................

Another error: The functions that calls reside in the same library, but it's eventually sat to work by external calls.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinNls.h>
    int LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH =256;
    wchar_t local_name[LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH]={0} ;//= new wchar_t
    int r = GetUserDefaultLocaleName(local_name, sizeof( sizeof(local_name)/sizeof(wchar_t) ) );
    if(r>0){
        wcout << "locale is " << local_name << "\n";
    }
```

debug error:
error: 'GetUserDefaultLocaleName' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Please show a [mre] of what you have tried and what isn't working. Note that the windows console is tricky to work with unicode correctly, the most reliable is to use `wcout` and print `std::wstring` rather than `cout`

Comment: 1252 is not a multi-byte encoding.  You are probably getting a utf8 string back, it will encode 2 bytes for a Danish character.  Use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar) to convert, pass CP_UTF8 for the 1st argument.

Comment: Note: the encoding your IDE uses for your source files has no impact on how your compiled code will interpret strings.

Comment: @Alan Birtles; You've already got the u8"The official ...
I store a 
string s  = "abcæøådgf"
in the library. It's no doubt size=9. 
In the external part that reads/calls it, it's string.size()=12
I made an edit!

Comment: From experience I fiddle with encodings in it's own console-tester. As of right now it has changed some litterals after changing encoding. When i try to edit those strings the console exits immidiately. It's touchy stuff. This is a copy/paste:
wstring whstr{L"luÃ¦Ã¸Ã¥se"};

Comment: @Hans Passant, I'll have to use it .. wstring will not accept the danish odd litterals

Comment: Maybe this link works:[link](https://onedrive.live.com/?id=382E99B169B58267%21579&cid=382E99B169B58267)
The first line of the code is running in main.cpp, the rest in the library. I'm testing in a functional app, hench the messy image. You can see the constant_names there. Wrong texture-fetch throws a question, blanks is my own foul-up